# Add an option in a builder

Tags: custom-post-types

I try to add a list of project in the builder of DIVI theme.

I have already managed to insert the project_tag list like this :

```
            <div class="et-pb-option">
            <label for="et_pb_project_tag">Choisir le(s) réalisateur(s): </label>
            <div class="et-pb-option-container">
            <% var et_pb_include_project_tag_temp = typeof et_pb_include_project_tag !== 'undefined' ? et_pb_include_project_tag.split( ',' ) : []; %>
END;

                $tag_array = get_terms( 'project_tag' );
                foreach ( $tag_array as $tag ) {
                    printf( '<label><input type="checkbox" name="et_pb_include_project_tag" value="%1$s"%3$s> %2$s</label><br/>',
                        esc_attr( $tag->term_id ),
                        esc_html( $tag->name ),
                        '<%= _.contains( et_pb_include_project_tag_temp, "' . $tag->term_id . '" ) ? checked="checked" : "" %>'
                    );
                }
echo <<<END

                <p class="description">Sélectionner le réalisateur.</p>
            </div> <!-- .et-pb-option-container -->
        </div> <!-- .et-pb-option -->
```

But I don't know how to do with parent custom type "project"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need a list of the taxonomies under your custom post type, or a list of posts from the custom post type

Comment: A list of posts from the custom post type... do you think it is possible ? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom query with `WP_Query` to get all posts from your post type. This is how a basic query will look like, you just need to tweak it to your needs

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=project&posts_per_page=-1' );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }

}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thank you ! But I have just a list of projects, not a checkboxes list ! I will search how to tweak it properly...

Comment: Just change `li` with something like `p`

Comment: I understand... What a shame ! ;) Thanks for your answers anyway.

Comment: If my answer was useful, please consider accepting it as a solution. Thank you